# How can I make a html element<p> from strings and other elements?

Tags: html, flutter, dart, dom

I use flutter with html package.
How can I make a html element

from strings and other elements?

```
Element elementLink = ...; //I created this earlier
String a = "text_1";
String b = "text_2";

Document document = Document();
Element newElement;

newElement = document.createElement('p);
```

As a result, I should get:

```
<html><body><p>text_1 <a href="https://example.com/">Example.com</a> text_2</p></body></html>
```

How can I do this?

```
newElement.append(a);
newElement.append(elementLink);
newElement.append(b);
```

This gives an error: "The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Node'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var p = document.createElement('p');
var a = document.createElement('a');

a.innerText = "Example.com";
a.setAttribute('href', 'https://example.com/');

document.querySelector('body').appendChild(p);
p.append('text_1');
//p.appendChild(a);
p.append(a);
p.append('text_2');
```

Comment: The method 'appendChild' isn't defined for the type 'Element'.

Comment: Have you tried using my code and you are getting this error?

Comment: Yes, there is no such method: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-html/Element-class.html

Comment: try - `p.append(a);` - `p.appendChild(a);` - Is there a mistake in this place? I have updated my code. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-html/AccessibleNode/appendChild.html